# return (rear+1)%MAX_SIZE == front ? true : false;

Tags: java

Hello Could anybody explain to me how can I read this log. 
What is is ? and :
How can I re-write it in simplest way. am still beginner. 
Thank you.

Comment: `? :` is the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Comment: I realize this has been closed, but for the future, @AhmedA - don't put edits in comments. Edit your question. You put a bunch of unformatted code in a comment, which is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it by removing the ternary operator:

```
return (rear+1)%MAX_SIZE == front;
```

Comment: oh good. thank you. so ? means questionable. : means either or. thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the link that Blackbelt posted above.  There's nothing 'questionable' about it :-)